# Phonegap iOS jquery fixed header not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, xcode, cordova

I have just started out coding my first iOS app on phonegap/xcode.
My current phonegap version is 3.1.0 and xcode is 5.0

As I want to implement some jquery mobile functions like fixed header/footer, I have implemented the scripts into my index.html but it still couldn't work.

Here are my codes for the fixed header/footer:

CSS:

```
  #topbar{
        display:block;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        width:320px;
        height:54px;
        background-color:#000;}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquerymobile.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquerymobile-1.3.2.js"</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="topbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, I think the jquery is not called into the app. How do I resolve this issue or which codes/scripts am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the jquery before the jquery mobile, and remember, to work with jquery mobile, it must be a version previous of 2.0.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! How do I import and which jquery files do I have to import?

Comment: the jquery is missing : <script  type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> and the css also <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />